# FusionCharts rendered in Javascript not printing

Tags: javascript, printing, fusioncharts

I'm using fusioncharts free and creating some 3d pie charts like so...

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;" id="chart1Adiv">FusionCharts</div>
<script language="JavaScript">
  var chart1A = new FusionCharts("./fusion_charts/FCF_Pie3D.swf","chart1Adiv","300","200");
  chart1A.setDataXML("<graph caption='1A' bgColor='ffffff' decimalPrecision='0' showPercentageValues='1' showNames='1' showValues='1' showPercentageInLabel='1' pieYScale='45' pieBorderAlpha='40' pieFillAlpha='70' pieSliceDepth='15' pieRadius='75'><set name='Pass' value='100' color='0000FF' /><set name='Fail' value='25' color='FF0000' /></graph>"");
  chart1A.render("chart1Adiv");
</script>
```

The graphs render just fine on the web page.
FusionCharts Free documentation reads:

```
To print a chart displayed in browser window, just right click on it and select Print or still better, use the browser's print button.
```

If I right click the actual pie chart and select print from the context menu the graph will print. My problem is that on the web page I'm generating more than one pie chart and need to print the entire page full of pie charts but when I select File->Print from the file menu none of the pie charts print but the rest of the html from the page does. Anyone else have this problem and/or a solution to this problem? So far I've tried this in both Firefox and Chrome with no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:  http://www.fusioncharts.com/forum/Topic11190-33-1.aspx#bm11207

Comment: I would add a small piece of information to @jerrygarciu's answer - there is an inherent problem with browsers printing Flash! As such, FusionCharts Free (being Flash only,) has very little workaround. On the other hand, FusionCharts v3 has a workaround that is termed as "Managed Print". In this, the charts generate an HTML5 canvas element in the background that is printed correctly.